# Laravel 8 – Model instance error - too few arguments to function __construct()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I’m kind of new to Laravel and the whole API architecture, so my question may seem dumb at first.

My basic setup:

- Laravel 8;
- PHP 8;

routes\api.php

```
Route::post('/categories/',[ApiCategoriesInsertController::class, 'insertCategories'], function($insertCategoriesResults) {
    return response()->json($insertCategoriesResults);
})->name('api.categories.insert');
```

\app\Http\Controllers\ApiCategoriesInsertController.php (created with php artisan make:controller)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

// Custom models.
use App\Models\CategoriesInsert;


class ApiCategoriesInsertController extends Controller
{
    private mixed $ciAPI;
    public function __construct(Request $req)
    {

    }

    public function insertCategories(Request $req): array
    {
        $this->ciAPI = new CategoriesInsert(['testing'=>'debug']);
        return [‘status’ => ‘OK’];
    }
}
```

\app\Models\CategoriesInsert.php (created with php artisan make:model)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CategoriesInsert extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function __construct(array $objParameters)
    {
        
    }
}
```

When I make a post to http://localhost:8000/api/categories, Laravel logs the following error:

```
local.ERROR: Too few arguments to function App\Models\CategoriesInsert::__construct(), 0 passed in … Too few arguments to function App\\Models\\CategoriesInsert::__construct(), 0 passed in …
```

Anyone knows what’s wrong or missing in my architecture?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make your model's constructor compatible with parent.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CategoriesInsert extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }
}
```

Also, notice, that when you call `new CategoriesInsert(['testing'=>'debug'])`, you do not save the data in your database. Use:

```php
$insert = new CategoriesInsert(['testing'=>'debug']);
$insert->save();
```

Or:

```php
CategoriesInsert::create(['testing'=>'debug']);
```

Comment: Made some progress. It doesn´t log the error anymore but I tried this to see what I´d get out: ```public function __construct(array $objParameters = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($objParameters);
        var_dump($objParameters);        
    }``` Doesn´t print out anything and I suspect that execution stops. Any idea of what´s happening?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to pass data to model

change your code to bellow code:

```
    public function insertCategories(Request $req): array
    {
        CategoriesInsert::create(['testing' => 'debug']);
        return [‘status’ => ‘OK’];
    }
```

key of passed array is your filed name in database, and value stored data

also you should define fillable parameter in model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'slug',
    'priority',
];
```

Comment: The $fillable part was important.